# Lenovo S340 Laptop Windows 10 power/wake-up fail

Tags: windows-10, laptop, power-management

If laptop lid is closed, and left for sufficient length of time (not certain how long is sufficient), the laptop will not wake up again, irrespective of whether it is connected to power or not. The fan blows a gale if and when plugged in, less so if on battery, but will still blow. Laptop charging light will not come on when plugged in. The laptop is unresponsive to any attempt to force-shutdown/restart.

If the battery is disconnected (requires removing the bottom shell), and then the power button held down for 30 sec while disconnected from power, the computer will switch on and function normally after reconnecting to power. In this state the battery can be reconnected, and the charge light will come on. The laptop can then be disconnected from power without problem. This lid can be closed *briefly* (a few seconds, at least), and re-opened with no problems, with or without connection to power.

If the lid is closed for any length of time, irrespective of connection to power, we start all over again. I assume it's some problem between power management and the hardware, but I'm not a Windows person, so I don't know where to start guessing.

I've also tried graceful power off/on cycles while the computer was working, and disconnecting the CMOS battery. Nothing affected the above behaviour.

Please does this make sense to anybody?

Comment: Update the BIOS and then update the Power Driver. Set the power properties (Control Panel, Power Options) for Suspend, Lid close property to Suspend. Turn Hibernation off temporarily while testing.

Comment: I've had a chance to try this -- no joy, unfortunately.

Comment: I am not sure I know. Lenovo laptops are normally good with Suspend capabilities. Did Suspend ever work?  If it did work once, you may need to back up and re-install Windows.

Comment: Yes, it worked as expected for almost a year. The change in behaviour doesn't appear to be correlated to anything obvious. Thanks for putting the thought into it!